# How do I view all org-mode TODOs that are not recurring, or not scheduled?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Weekly, I try to make sure that there are no TODOs I want to have scheduled that I've missed. So I look through the list of all TODO entries (`C-c a t`). This is great; it shows only open TODOs, so I don't have to waste time skipping past all the stuff I've already done.

But really, I don't want the list of all TODOs; If something is scheduled, or recurring, I don't want to see it in this list. I'd rather only see things that I could be missing, and I'm not missing something scheduled tomorrow that repeats every two days.

One can run [`org-agenda-filter-by-tag`](http://orgmode.org/manual/Filtering_002flimiting-agenda-items.html#index-org_002dagenda_002dfilter_002dby_002dtag-1196) with `/`, but either it can't filter by scheduled/recurring status, or I'm not sure of the way to use it that way. Given that the list of tags that show up when you press `TAB` doesn't include anything like "unscheduled", I'd bet this isn't the tool I want.

So there are two possible solutions. While I'd prefer the first, having the second is also a possible solution for this problem.

1. How can I view all unscheduled open TODOs?
2. How can I view all open TODOs (scheduled or not) that are not recurring?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a custom agenda view which sets [`org-agenda-skip-function`](http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-agenda-views.html) using `org-agenda-skip-entry-if`. Something like this:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("c" . "My Custom Agendas")
        ("cu" "Unscheduled TODO"
         ((todo ""
                ((org-agenda-overriding-header "\nUnscheduled TODO")
                 (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'timestamp)))))
         nil
         nil)))
```

Comment: This will skip anything with a timestamp.  `(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'notscheduled)` will skip only scheduled items.

Comment: @erikstokes -- I think you mean `(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'scheduled)`, not `'notscheduled`.

Comment: This answer is great, but I would suggest not using `setq`, but instead `push` to just add a new entry to the list, rather than setting it entirely afresh. Also, I'm not sure why the todo symbol and its arguments need to be doubly-nested; it seems to work fine if they're at the top level of the quoted list.

Comment: @zck Yes, that's what I meant.  The double nesting thing is if you want multiple blocks in one agenda view.  This one only has one block, so it's the same as being at the top level.

Comment: @zck I couldn't make it work with `push` instead of `setq`. What was your code?

Comment: @miguelmorin something like `(push (list "c" "My Custom Agendas") org-agenda-custom-commands)`. What's not working?

Comment: @zck That syntax works. What I couldn't find the syntax to include the `... "Unscheduled TODO" ... (org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'scheduled) ...` inside your syntax for `(push ... org-agenda-custom-commands)`.

Comment: @miguelmorin does `(push '("cu" "Unscheduled TODO" ((todo "" ((org-agenda-overriding-header "\nUnscheduled TODO") (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'timestamp))))) nil nil) org-agenda-custom-commands)` work?

Comment: @zck Yes, that does work. But I was unable to include the section `("c" . "My custom agendas")` from the original answer. I get `Wrong type argument: listp, "My Custom Agendas"`.

Comment: How to add "except those unscheduled items with tag X"? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can now satisfy these requirements without a custom agenda by customizing `org-agenda-todo-ignore-scheduled`.  It also comes in these flavours: `org-agenda-todo-ignore-with-date` `org-agenda-todo-ignore-deadlines` and others.

Comment: Specifically you can set `org-agenda-todo-ignore-scheduled` to `'all` to ignore any item that has a schedule (and likewise for deadlines).  `'past` and `'future` are also valid settings.